# How To restrict user to not leave the exam window in online exam conduction?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am Developing a React Application for online MCQS exams. I want to restrict the user to not leave the exam screen until it completes the exam or time goes over. 
I used React Full-screen component for full screen,but on pressing the esc button it leaves the full screen.
Is there any other way to achieved full screen rather than Full Screen API.
Or any other way to implement the restrictions of online exam conduction.
Also I want to Handle Some Key combinations like Alt+F4 , Ctrl+Shift+Tab.

I have used the Event Handler for the keyDown for esc button. but it fires after the full screen closes.
Also I have Used Event Handler for F4 and all keyboard keys. but Alt+F4 close the browser.

Comment: I am afraid you can't do this since your application is running in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's not possible to force a website (or web application, respectively) to stay for an unlimited time in fullscreen mode. The reason is pretty simple: user security. As Craig Buckler explains [in this blog post](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-full-screen-api/):

> If you can force an app to run full-screen, the user loses their browser, taskbar and standard operating system controls. They may not be able to close the window or, worse, nefarious developers could emulate the OS and trick users into handing over passwords, credit card details, etc.

I guess the only possibility would be to configure the web browser on a specific computer to always run a certain page in fullscreen mode. But I guess that would require administrator rights and probably not all browsers might have flags or configuration options for this.

---

**Edit:** Another option would be to create a standalone executable file that opens a pre-configured browser instance in fullscreen mode. Have a look at [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) for desktop or [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) for mobile devices for instance. But please note that this might take much more time to build and deploy than just programming the web app itself, if you have never worked with one of these tools before.

Comment: you right if it happen it will be so dangerous, a lot of people will use it to stole date